# Android Emulator: Remove An Activity which is started as startActivityForResult from backstack

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

In My application I want to apply logout functionality. For that I placed a menu item for Logout. If Logout is pressed . I called the LoginActivity.

```
Intent login=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
      login.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                  startActivity(login);
```

But the problem is , In My application i called lot of activity as StartActivityForResult().
All these activities are still in backstack. How can i remove all these activities (StartActivityForResult) from backstack.

**When I run in my andriod device , I am not facing this problem. But while running in my emulator i face this problem**

Thanks,
Sridhar.

Comment: also I write android:noHistory=true in Manifest xml

Comment: What for do you use those Activities? Starting an Activity for result means you open it just to get a result out of it, then it should be finished. Probably you should redesign your application.

Comment: For eg, take SelectItemActivity. I called it as StartActivityforResult. this activity for multi selection of items

Comment: So you should call finish() on this Activity after you call setResult(), then you'll go back to the originating Activity and the SelectItemActivity will be destroyed.

Comment: yes, Intent i = new Intent(); i.putExtras("id",selectedIds);setResult(Result_ok,i);finish()

Comment: i write the above code on button ok onclick method

Comment: So you needn't worry about this Activity, it will be destroyed and eliminated from the backstack.

Comment: But im my emulator, I face this by pressing back button in LoginActivity